# What is the best way to check if audio embedded in video is ambisonic?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc, mediainfo

We are making 360 video player for VR headsets using Unity. We are trying to achieve spatial audio. The easiest case is when video and audio are in separated files, but now we decided to support also videos with embedded audio. I need to know before i load video if audio is ambisonic or not. I'm looking for an easy way to decide if audio is ambisonic in order to separate it from video and convert to .tbe file, which is currently supported by our app.

I was trying to use ffmpeg:

```
$./ffmpeg.exe -i ~/Videos/video.mp4
```

and got:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:/Users/Medion/Videos/video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:11:39.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17290 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 16497 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      stereo3d: top and bottom
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp, 778 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 4.0, fltp, 4 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:3(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

but I don't see any line that could indicate that audio is ambisonic. I see that there are 4 channels in streams #0:1 and #0:2, but I bet it's not enough.

I've also tried MediaInfo but it's the same thing:

```
General
CompleteName                     : C:\Users\Medion\Videos\video.mp4
Format/String                    : MPEG-4
Format_Profile                   : Base Media
CodecID/String                   : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
FileSize/String                  : 1.41 GiB
Duration/String                  : 11 min 39 s
OverallBitRate_Mode/String       : Variable
OverallBitRate/String            : 17.3 Mb/s
Encoded_Application/String       : Lavf57.56.101

Video
ID/String                        : 1
Format/String                    : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format_Profile                   : High@L5.2
Format_Settings                  : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format_Settings_CABAC/String     : Yes
Format_Settings_RefFrames/String : 3 frames
Format_Settings_GOP              : M=3, N=29
CodecID                          : avc1
CodecID/Info                     : Advanced Video Coding
Duration/String                  : 11 min 39 s
BitRate_Mode/String              : Variable
BitRate/String                   : 16.5 Mb/s
BitRate_Maximum/String           : 20.0 Mb/s
Width/String                     : 3 840 pixels
Height/String                    : 2 160 pixels
DisplayAspectRatio/String        : 16:9
FrameRate_Mode/String            : Constant
FrameRate/String                 : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Standard                         : NTSC
ColorSpace                       : YUV
ChromaSubsampling/String         : 4:2:0
BitDepth/String                  : 8 bits
ScanType/String                  : Progressive
Bits-(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.066
StreamSize/String                : 1.34 GiB (95%)
Language/String                  : English
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2017-06-13 17:37:51
colour_range                     : Limited
colour_primaries                 : BT.709
transfer_characteristics         : BT.709
matrix_coefficients              : BT.709
Codec configuration box          : avcC

Audio #1
ID/String                        : 2
Format/String                    : AAC LC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
CodecID                          : mp4a-40-2
Duration/String                  : 11 min 39 s
Source_Duration/String           : 11 min 39 s
BitRate_Mode/String              : Constant
BitRate/String                   : 779 kb/s
Channel(s)/String                : 4 channels
ChannelLayout                    : C L R Cb
SamplingRate/String              : 48.0 kHz
FrameRate/String                 : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression_Mode/String          : Lossy
StreamSize/String                : 64.9 MiB (5%)
Source_StreamSize/String         : 64.9 MiB (5%)
Default/String                   : Yes
AlternateGroup/String            : 1
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2017-06-13 17:37:51

Audio #2
ID/String                        : 3
Format/String                    : AAC LC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
CodecID                          : mp4a-40-2
Duration/String                  : 11 min 39 s
Source_Duration/String           : 11 min 39 s
BitRate_Mode/String              : Variable
BitRate/String                   : 4 900 b/s
BitRate_Maximum/String           : 266 kb/s
Channel(s)/String                : 4 channels
ChannelLayout                    : C L R Cb
SamplingRate/String              : 48.0 kHz
FrameRate/String                 : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression_Mode/String          : Lossy
StreamSize/String                : 418 KiB (0%)
Source_StreamSize/String         : 418 KiB (0%)
Default/String                   : No
AlternateGroup/String            : 1
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2017-06-13 17:37:51

Audio #3
ID/String                        : 4
Format/String                    : AAC LC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
CodecID                          : mp4a-40-2
Duration/String                  : 11 min 39 s
Source_Duration/String           : 11 min 39 s
BitRate_Mode/String              : Variable
BitRate/String                   : 2 275 b/s
BitRate_Maximum/String           : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)/String                : 2 channels
ChannelLayout                    : L R
SamplingRate/String              : 48.0 kHz
FrameRate/String                 : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression_Mode/String          : Lossy
StreamSize/String                : 194 KiB (0%)
Source_StreamSize/String         : 194 KiB (0%)
Default/String                   : No
AlternateGroup/String            : 1
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2017-06-13 17:37:51
```

I assume that I don't know what to look for in those outputs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like there is no info in your file about if it is ambisonic. Are you sure your analyzed file is ambisonic? Can you share a sample file so we could check if there is some unsupported metadata saying that it is ambisonic?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot share a sample, because it's our client's video, which we've got for some tests. I assumed it's ambisonic, because there is scene where there is a noise above the viewer and when I was rotating my head I could hear it in the right spot. By the right spot i mean: when I tilt my head to the right side i heard noise in my left ear. I was watching on Gear VR in Oculus Videos.

Comment: I can share instead other video which is ambisonic for sure:
https://voyagerapps.com/sunken_1k_h265_200kbps_1024x512_0020_0030_mono360.mp4
You have to download it to play it right.
I could even see:
    Channels: ambisonic
in VLC codec info tool.
Could you tell me how can I decide in Unity if this file has ambiconic sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MediaInfo development snapshots](https://mediaarea.net/download/snapshots/binary/mediainfo/) (mini 2190520-2) have now support of [Spatial Audio RFC (draft)](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/blob/master/docs/spatial-audio-rfc.md) metadata (such metadata is in the file you provided as an example), and display information this way:

```
Channel layout                           : Ambisonics (W X Y Z)
```